# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hello I am new to Laravel, I am developing a create form for posting where users can create a blog post basically with laravel however when I try to crate the post I am getting an error all the time:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

Here is my form:

```
@extends('master')


@section('content')

<h1>Selling your Home?</h1>




<form action="/flyers"  enctype="multpart/form-data" method="post"  >

  @inject('countries','App\Http\Utilities\Country')
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 form-signin">
           {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="street">Street:</label>

                <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control" value="{{old('street')}}" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="city">City:</label>

                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" value="{{old('city')}}" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="zip">Zip/ Postal Code:</label>

                <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="form-control" value="{{old('zip')}}" required>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="country">Country:</label>

                <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" required>
                    @foreach($countries::all() as $country=>$code)

                    <option value="{{$code}}">{{$country}}</option>

                    @endforeach
                </select>

            </div>

             <div class="form-group">

                <label for="country">State</label>

                <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="form-control" value="{{old('state')}}" required>


            </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="price">Sale Price:</label>

                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" value="{{old('price')}}">

            </div>


             <div class="form-group">

                <label for="description">Home Description:</label>

                <textarea name="description" id="description" class ="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"  value="{{old('description')}}"></textarea>



            </div>


      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Flyer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

</form>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an 'i' on your code:

should be: `enctype="multipart/form-data`"

instead of:

```
enctype="multpart/form-data"
```

Comment: face palm. thank you.